# EXT JS:password can be seen from firebug

Tags: extjs

Using extjs text field with input type='password'
The username and password can be seen from firebug when click login button. Is there any way to make it safe and invisible?

Answer (score 0):

On the client-side, passwords in fields stored in memory can always be retrieved locally; there is nothing you can do about this. This is also how scripts can work with these fields.

You probably should be more concerned about the security of the password's transmission, the encryption and so forth.

Comment: How can i encrypt this password?

Comment: If you're using the `https` protocol, the form data is already encrypted on transmission.

Comment: If you need an extra level of encryption, try using HTTPS with MD5.  A quick google search will find you several implementations of MD5 in Javascript

Comment: Do you mean, hash the password with MD5 before sending it? If so, that's a great idea, as only the hashes need to be compared.